# Foreach in jstl c tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I´m using jstl in jsp, creating a object result from a DTO, when I use it in this way:

```
<c:if test="${not empty result.billedConsumptionActive}">
    <p><c:out value="${result.billedConsumptionActive}"></c:out></p>
</c:if>
```

This return and print:

`ConsumptionDTO [consumptionHour00=37.6, consumptionHour01=null, consumptionHour02=null, consumptionHour03=50, consumptionHour04=null, consumptionHour05=null, consumptionHour06=12.5, consumptionHour07=null]`

But when I try to use it in a foreach statement:

```
<c:if test="${not empty result.billedConsumptionActive}">
    <c:forEach var="window" items="${result}">
        <td><c:out value="${result.billedConsumptionActive}"/></td> 
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

I got an error, and I cant explain why. There's another way to call `items="${result}`??

Comment: `forEach` works with collections. Do you have a collection in your DTO?

Comment: Hi Paul here is the DTO: 
`public class LtEmConsumptionPerHourResponseDTO {
    private ConsumptionDTO billedConsumptionActive;
    ...
}` And the other one:
`public class ConsumptionDTO {
    @NeolClientField(name = "consumptionHour00")
    private String consumptionHour00;

    @NeolClientField(name = "consumptionHour01")
    private String consumptionHour01;

    ...
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty result.billedConsumptionActive}">
    <c:forEach var="window" items="${result.billedConsumptionActive}">
        <td><c:out value="${window}"/></td> 
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```